# GWT: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied

Tags: gwt

I am not sure why this is happening: What I changed was I went from Classic Dev Mode to Super Dev Mode - I can't remember why I did that because since then I am **again**(!) trying to make this run. I don't know what the factorial I changed but now I am getting this:

```
Jun 08, 2015 1:57:41 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.security.SecurityManagerInstaller install
WARNING: Unable to delete dynamic policy file: C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Temp\test798307262776049603.policy
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\Temp\test798307262776049603.policy" "delete")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkDelete(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.delete(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.SecurityManagerInstaller.install(SecurityManagerInstaller.java:107)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:251)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:84)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)

Unable to start embedded HTTP server
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create a DevAppServer
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:266)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:84)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "getPolicy")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Policy.getPolicy(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.SecurityManagerInstaller.install(SecurityManagerInstaller.java:104)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:251)
    ... 12 more
[ERROR] Failure in unit cache map load.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "E:\java\mahlzeit-web\mahlzeit-web\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-c04dfa348afbdd12c2a9ddc3bc36901a78fa6812-0000014DD072583D" "read")
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.awaitUnitCacheMapLoad(PersistentUnitCache.java:523)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.find(PersistentUnitCache.java:428)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:548)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:499)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.initWithoutPrecompile(Recompiler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.maybePrecompile(Outbox.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.<init>(Outbox.java:61)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeOutboxes(CodeServer.java:156)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.SuperDevListener$1.run(SuperDevListener.java:84)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "E:\java\mahlzeit-web\mahlzeit-web\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-c04dfa348afbdd12c2a9ddc3bc36901a78fa6812-0000014DD072583D" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.loadUnitMap(PersistentUnitCache.java:566)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.access$800(PersistentUnitCache.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$4.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "E:\java\mahlzeit-web\mahlzeit-web\src\com\mahlzeit\web\client\service\LoginServiceAsync.java" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.lastModified(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.FileResource.getLastModified(FileResource.java:46)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:552)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:499)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.initWithoutPrecompile(Recompiler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.maybePrecompile(Outbox.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.<init>(Outbox.java:61)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeOutboxes(CodeServer.java:156)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.SuperDevListener$1.run(SuperDevListener.java:84)
[ERROR] Error during shutdown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "E:\java\mahlzeit-web\mahlzeit-web\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-c04dfa348afbdd12c2a9ddc3bc36901a78fa6812-0000014DD075526C" "delete")
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$5.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:301)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "E:\java\mahlzeit-web\mahlzeit-web\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-c04dfa348afbdd12c2a9ddc3bc36901a78fa6812-0000014DD075526C" "delete")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkDelete(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.delete(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.closeCurrentCacheFile(PersistentUnitCache.java:540)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.access$700(PersistentUnitCache.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$3.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:218)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.checkShutdownAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.shutdownNow(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$5.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:311)
```

Everybody knows that the way Windows works encourages programs to spit their shift into a so called temporary directory that you can find under `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\` and that has been created but never tried to be avoided just to annoy **you** - the user. I don't know *why* this is a problem now all of a sudden - of course it is my fault because it must have been me who has changed something - but I can't figure out *what* I've changed s.t. this problem emerges now.

Creating a new GWT project with the default greeting example works without any troubles - running in Super Dev Mode & in Classic Dev Mode.

What does it want from me?

---

**As a side note:** Since I started using GWT I'm running from one problem into another. I can't remember GWT being such a pain in the asset but the number of times I've been thinking that this tool just freaking hates me is too damn high. So if there's anybody out there who want to tip me over go ahead. All I want is a rather simple Web Interface to allow logged in users to manipulate certain data inside a database - but giving it some structure of course.

Comment: Looks like you're not running your IDE with sufficient permissions on the temp directory.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Well I am running Eclipse as admin. The other thing is that it works if I just create another project containing the default GWT "Hello World!" project. I am not 100% sure but I think we can exclude that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason for this exception is, that you are using Google App Engine and have added server side libraries to your project.

To solve this issue: disable Google App Engine or remove the server side libs.

Take a look here:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_Troubleshooting.html#AccessControlException_access_denied

Hope that helps.

Comment: It would not make sense to remove the Engine I am intending to use. :)

Comment: Are you using server side libs in your projects?

Comment: I am not sure what counts as server side libs but I am using e.g. Hibernate and two other projects that are referenced as dependencies in my GWT project.

Comment: It looks like you have something to do to get Hibernate running on GAE. https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-jpatools

Answer (score 0):

I see in your stacktrace you have problems with two very different paths. The one on C: and the other on E:\java\mahlzeit.... It is possible that your project has this hardcoded somewhere? Search for that string in your project and change it to whatever you need.

The other thing I (now) notice is that at the bottom there is another problem, the modifyThread policy. Perhaps when you create the Hello World project it defaults to one runtime environment and your current project is using another that has special policies settings.

Comment: No, the project does not have any hard coded paths. The path that does something on my C:\ drive is pointing just to the \temp directory.

Comment: Ok I think I should have commented instead of answering... :/ I just edited my answer to include something about environment policies. Maybe that?

Comment: Hi, any news on this?